# Troubling to specify parameter files with oracle database into c directory

Tags: database, oracle

Currently I just switched to Oracle database from Mysql now as i read freaky docs from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/create003.htm#ADMIN11077).

It says you must need to specify a `parameter file` but not being able to do that.
I mean i'm unable to find `Oracle_home` and i'm using windows 8 so it denies me to create any sort of files in `C:\ directory` .. Please guide me as well to do setup with Oracle database.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you install an OFA-compliant database, using Oracle Universal Installer defaults, then Oracle home (known as ORACLE_HOME in this guide) is located beneath ORACLE_BASE. It contains subdirectories for Oracle Database software executables and network files.

ORACLE_BASE-/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1 
with subdirectories like:
bin,
rdbms,
sqlplus,
etc